Is it better to add a comma between 'house' and 'in'?
From Cambridge Dictionary:

They never parked the big van in front of the house in order not to upset the neighbours.

Without a comma, there is a reading of

Park the big van in front of the house in order not to upset the
neighbours. But they won't do this.

With a comma,

They never parked the big van in front of the house , in order not to upset the neighbours.

Is that right?

Do you mean that it's possible to understand the sentence as meaning 'Parking the van in front of the house would not upset the neighbours'? Common sense makes that interpretation highly unlikely.

@Kate Bunting The meaning derived from syntactic analysis does not follow logic. But the result of semantic analysis is logical. The answer below says that even without the comma, it's still true. But maybe it is the case for this sentence. So I want to make sure whether in order to avoid this syntactic illogic, adding a comma is reasonable.

@Araucaria - Not here any more. Ok, I have reopen it.

The sentence doesn't need a comma because it's all one thought. So

They never parked the big van in front of the house in order not to upset the neighbours.

But even better would be to put the reason first.

In order not to upset the neighbours they never parked the big van in front of the house.

And if you want to nail it, try for less than two negatives (i.e. not and never) in a single thought...

To avoid upsetting the neighbours they never parked the big van in front of the house.

